# Why are the pins in this RJ45 port not all identical?

Tags: ethernet

As shown on the picture below, the pins on these Ethernet ports are not all the same.

It looks like pin 3, 5, 7 and 8 (or 1, 2, 4 and 6?) are elevated in order to make contact, but not the others.

I'm seeing this on a RJ45 Cat6 STP wall plug like shown below.

Why is that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: On what device are you seeing this?

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks, I've edited my original question.

Comment: I've seen both styles of pins used, but never together. There's no logical reason to mix them, or have that pattern of pairs.

Comment: The early-contact pins are 1, 2, 4, 6. 1-2 is a pair, but 4 and 6 belong to different pairs. All pins need to be used for Cat 6. Why the pins are staggered is beyond me, likely just mechanical reasons. Both your photos seem to show different jacks though.

Comment: Blow up the sockets on the 2nd image, and you will not see anything like what is on the first image. Those are two different devices. Even on the first image, the pins that are not raised will make contact when the jack is inserted into the socket. Notice that they are bent up to meet the contacts in the the jack.

Comment: @RonMaupin The second image is taken from the shop's website, just to show what kind of device we are talking about, as per request. It is the device I bought - but the first image shows a close-up of the ports (a picture I took) and I was intrigued, hence my question.

Comment: Read Ricky's comment. All the pins in the socket will connect to the jack when it is inserted. Both styles are in use. In one, you have the pins bent up to meet the jack, and the other the pins bend down when the jack is inserting into the socket.

Comment: I've now edited my post to show a photo of the device I have, to avoid confusion.

Comment: OK I can gather from the replies here that it's rare to set up the pins like that, but that they will make a connection with all the pins in the plug nonetheless, and that they are like that likely for mechanical reasons.

Comment: I have multiple old Cisco switches sitting in my basement, and two of them exhibit a variant of this phenomenon.  Both my 2960 (100Mbps, no PoE) and my 3560 (100Mbps, with PoE) have pins 3 and 5 elevated to contact first.  The same 3560 also has a single 1Gbps port at the right which does NOT exhibit this phenomenon.  I also have a 3750X (Gigabit, no PoE) and a 4948 (Gigabit, no PoE) that do not exhibit this phenomenon.